# Service integration issuer certificate not found

Tags: azure, azure-servicebus-queues

I am using PluginResgistration tool to create an azure service endpoint. I have Configured and saved ACS. I am using persistent queue as Contract. While I click on the "Save and Verify authentication" I am getting the above error. I am performing all these actions because I want to receive messages through Service Bus from CRM.